# circulation of class in c++, how to use their constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

i need two class which are form a circulation, both have ther own members but along with a copy of other class, lets consider this example.

```
class lower; 
class upper{
    int uA;
    lower L;
    upper(){
    uA=0;   
    //how to initialize lower here using lower's constructor 
    }
};

class lower{
    int lA;
    upper U;
    lower(){
    lA=0; 
    //how to initialize upper here using upper's constructor 
   }

};
```

now i need a upper object `upper L` in main(); and i want all variable of it initialize with zero (for default constructor) but i don't now how to handle circulation of these constructor so get initialed `lower L` within upper

Comment: This layout is impossible in C++. At least one of L or U must be a pointer or reference.

Comment: ok you can modify this example as you want. can use pointers but i only need that when i initialize upper with zero its lower also  get zero .

Comment: why do you need an instance of upper in lower if you already have a lower in upper?

Comment: We [had this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11906666/596781) just earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
class upper;
class lower{
    friend class upper;
    int lA;
    upper* U;
    void setUpper(upper* u)
    {
        U = u;
    }
    public:

    lower(){
    lA=0; 
    U = 0; 
   }
};

class upper{
    int uA;
    lower* L;
    public:
    upper(lower* l){
    uA=0;   
    L = l;
    l->setUpper(this); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    lower* l = new lower();
    upper* u = new upper(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Although you need to add desctructors to clean up the pointers, as appropriate, or delete
lower from upper?

Also you should investigate your datastructures and see if you could get rid of the 
circular dependency - it's likely to cause you problems in future.

Comment: or you could avoid the mess and just have a regular instance of lower inside upper?

Comment: thanks. i will try to remove circular dependency but i think this type of situation very common.

Answer (score 1):

Like this, (as KennyTM says you need to use pointers)

```
class lower; 

class upper
{
    int uA;
    lower* L;
    upper() : uA(0), L(new L)
    {
    }
};

class lower
{
    int lA;
    upper* U;
    lower() : lA(0), U(new U)
    {
    }
};
```

There's plenty of issues with this code, but hopefully it answers your question.

Comment: Don't know who up voted my answer, it's garbage. I'd delete it if I could.